# Is there a post-Castro plan for Cuba?

Tags: cuba, succession

With both Castro brothers well into their 80s, is there a plan for succession in the Cuban leadership? I am curious if the next leader will be of the '59 revolution generation or not

Answer (score 6):

Raul Castro's current term ends in 2018, and he has [announced it will be his last](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/25/world/americas/raul-castro-to-step-down-as-cubas-president-in-2018.html?_r=0). His heir apparent is [Miguel Díaz-Canel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_D%C3%ADaz-Canel), Cuba's first vice president since February 2013. He was born in 1960, a year after the revolution ended.

That said, a new candidate to succeed Raul may arise from the 7th Congress of the Communist Party of Cuba, scheduled for April 2016. [José Ramón Machado Ventura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Ram%C3%B3n_Machado_Ventura), the party's second secretary could be a possibility, even though he's also in his 80s.

Furthermore, the congress is rumored to bring changes in electoral laws, and that there might be a general election implementing those changes right after (instead of 2018). Right now we don't know what those changes will be, and how they'll affect succession (if at all).

Comment: I read that Raul said he won't continue after 2018 so will be interesting to see how things pan out